# Python - TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object despite checks for None

Tags: python

I am trying to follow [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/optimizing-blackjack-strategy-through-monte-carlo-methods-cbb606e52d1b) tutorial. The generate_episode function returns three lists, and in the first_visit_mc_prediction function, the generate_episode function is used to set three lists to the returned lists. However, when I run it I get `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`. I have tried to add checks if any of the lists are none and only then set the lists to the returned ones. I have done this like this:

```
if generate_episode(policy, env) is not None:
   states, _, rewards = generate_episode(policy, env)
```

This still gives the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christophwiederin/PycharmProjects/monte-carlo-simulation/blackjack.py", line 74, in <module>
    value = first_visit_mc_prediction(sample_policy, env, n_episodes = 500000)
  File "/Users/christophwiederin/PycharmProjects/monte-carlo-simulation/blackjack.py", line 50, in first_visit_mc_prediction
    states, _, rewards = generate_episode(policy, env)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

How can I fix this?

I have also tried adding if none checks in the generate_episode function (only returning the lists if all lists are not none) but this still does not help and gives same error.
This is the generate_episode function:

```
def generate_episode(policy, env):
    
    # we initialize the list for storing states, actions, and rewards
    states, actions, rewards = [], [], []
    
    # Initialize the gym environment
    observation = env.reset()
    
    while True:
        
        # append the states to the states list
        states.append(observation)
        
        # now, we select an action using our sample_policy function and append the action to actions list
         
        action = sample_policy(observation)
        actions.append(action)
        
        # We perform the action in the environment according to our sample_policy, move to the next state 
        # and receive reward
        observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        rewards.append(reward)
        
        # Break if the state is a terminal state (i.e. done)
        if done:
             break
                
    return states, actions, rewards
```

I tried replacing the last line with:

```
    if actions is not None:
       print("actions not none")
       if rewards is not None:
          print("rewards not none")
          if states is not None:
             print("states not none")
             return states, actions, rewards
```

calling it with single output x = generate_episode(policy, env) and print(x) gives:

```
([(14, 6, False)], [1], [0.0])
None
([(13, 2, False)], [1], [0.0])
([(14, 5, False)], [1], [0.0])
None
... going on with similar values
```

Comment: please add the exception message with all the error stack

Comment: It's pretty clear that `generate_episode` will always return 3 lists, so your problem must be coming from somewhere else. Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: Ok i just added the stack trace

Comment: call it with single output x = generate_episode(policy, env) and print(x). what is x value?

Comment: well i think you get more than 3 outputs. len(x) should be 3 for your expected unpacking

Comment: I added the output of print(x) in my question

Comment: The `generate_episode()` function you've shown us is incapable of returning `None`.  So this is obviously not the function that's actually being called - it's been overridden by another definition, had a decorator applied to it, or something like that.

Comment: hmm ok strange. Not sure where that would be happening

Comment: I'd run the script with [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) and stepped through the function to see where `None` is coming from.

Comment: Is it possible for two calls to generate_policy with the same parameters to give different results based on a change of state of the environment?  Your call `if generate_episode(p, e) is not None:` could change the results returned inside that if block.
  Also, within generate_episode, you have an unused parameter named `policy`.  Was this meant to be the callable `sample_policy` used within the function?

Comment: the print(x) you show is single print(x) or several calls?

Comment: @LiorCohen several calls. its in the for loop so some are none and some give three lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my error by setting the returned lists to one variable `data = generate_episode_data(policy, env)` and then checking for none like this: `if data is not None:`. I am still not sure where the none comes from but at least not typeerror anymore

Comment: All functions in Python return `None` by default if you don't return anything else. So, the `None` comes from not returning anything from the `generate_episode` function and then trying to unpack `None` to the tuple `states, _, rewards` in `states, _, rewards = generate_episode(policy, env)`.